# Where is the feedback form for the Release Notes?

Tags: release-notes

In the Release Notes, it is stated

> Feedback forms — As you’re working with our documentation in
>   Salesforce Help, release notes, or developer guides, look for the
>   feedback form and vote up or down. Add comments if you have them.

So where are these forms? I can't find them.

Example of a Release Notes page. Can anyone point me to the feedback section?
[image: Release notes page]

Answer (score 1):

Click the feedback icon located on the right side of the page.

[image: Feedback icon highlighted]

Other pages may have feedback at the end of the page.

[image: Feedback hands]

I believe they're working on a way to make things more universal, which is why this was called out in the release notes.

Comment: Thanks. I added an image to my question. No feedback section on that page, unfortunately.

Comment: @SanderdeJong That's curious. I suspect it's an oversight. Maybe ask on an official communication channel (e.g. Twitter's asksalesforce, or via Help)?

Answer (score 0):

For https://developer.salesforce.com, the feedback form link is at bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: I added an image of the page I was looking at, to my question. No feedback section there, unfortunately.